# ArcGIS-JS-API failed to execute query

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm trying to execute this (it's JavaScript but it doesn't matter):

```
queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {
```

and I get an error:

> Failed to execute query

These are the parameters:

```
var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(path);
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
```

To show how are defined what I get with them, `console.log` shows this:

console.log('query', query);

```
outFields: Array(1)
0: "*"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
returnGeometry: false
spatialRelationship: "esriSpatialRelIntersects"
where: "codigo_pos = 8150215"
```

console.log('queryTask', queryTask);

```
gdbVersion: undefined
normalization: true
source: undefined
url: "https://arcgis.XXX.com/arcgis/rest/services/XXX/XXX/MapServer/4"
_countHandler: ƒ ()
_errorHandler: ƒ ()
_executeForIdsHandler: ƒ ()
_extentHandler: ƒ ()
_handler: ƒ ()
_relationshipQueryHandler: ƒ ()
_url: {path: "https://arcgis.XXX.com/arcgis/rest/serv…XXX/XXX/MapServer/4", query: null}
__proto__: Object
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you please check the result from the query using the dev tools (Network tab)?
It probably gets you a better approach about what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `queryTask.execute(params)` [returns a promise](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html#execute),
in order to handle the results, read the results via the `then` clause

`queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
    console.log(results.features);
  });`